# what is difference between having quote and not having quote in json string

Tags: json, kotlin

Got a string with key/value pair and some one in it having quote (the quote should be kept as part of the string). Would like to parse the key/value pair into a map.
So use `JSONObject(inputString)` to construct a JSONObject from source string, then build the map from it.

(using org.json.JSONObject with Android api 31)

```
String theStr = "{
     mKey1:mVal1,
     mKey2:\"mVal2\",
     \"mKey3\":\"mVal3\"}";
```

after call the
`val map = jsonStrToMap(theStr)`
to generate the map from the string, the quote is lost at calling

`val jObject = JSONObject(inputString)` 
to covert to the JSONObject.

The trace log:

```
inputString: ({mKey1:mVal1,mKey2:"mVal2","mKey3":"mVal3"}),
jObject = JSONObject(inputString) => {"mKey1":"mVal1","mKey2":"mVal2","mKey3":"mVal3"}
+++ jObject.getString(mKey1) ==> mVal1 
+++ jObject.getString(mKey2) ==> mVal2 
+++ jObject.getString(mKey3) ==> mVal3 
return map: {mKey3=mVal3, mKey2=mVal2, mKey1=mVal1}
```

the function using the JSONObject:

```
fun jsonStrToMap(inputString: String?): HashMap<String, String> {
    val map = HashMap<String, String>()
    
    try {
        val jObject = JSONObject(inputString)
        
        System.out.println("\ninputString: ($inputString),\njObject = JSONObject(inputString) => $jObject")
        
        val keys = jObject.keys()
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            val key = keys.next()
            val value = jObject.getString(key)
            
            System.out.println("+++ jObject.getString($key) ==> $value ")

            map[key] = value
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) { }
    return map
        .also {
            System.out.println("return map: $it")
        }
}
```

Question: How to keep the quote with the string when using `JSONObject(inputString)`

Comment: Which quote do you feel is lost?  NB: `strStr` does not represent valid JSON. Keys in JSON should always be quoted.

Comment: we got string from remote, some key are not quoted. But it's the value if it has quote and we want to keep.

Comment: None of the values in that (invalid) JSON have quotes. The only quotes present in that JSON are delimiters that are part of the JSON syntax. They are not part of values.

Comment: let's say theStr is "{\"mKey3\":\"mKey3\"}", and want keep the the quote with "mVal3". But the JSONObjeect(theStr) will get {"mKey3":"mKey3"} instead of {"mKey3":"\"mKey3\""}

Comment: Did you understand my previous comment? `theStr` does not define any values with quotes. Those quotes are delimiters. If you want it to be as you describe at the very end of your last phrase, then *that* should be encoded in your JSON.

Comment: I guess the string we got remote is not right (does not hav the quote, it should be {"mKey3":"\"mVal3\""}, if would like the quote to be part of the value string.

Comment: Since already it is not valid JSON, you should contact the owner of the remote service. You should not write code that tries to "fix" badly formatted JSON.

Comment: hmm, we have been receiving the "json string" like "{k:v, k1:v1}", flat normal string (no quote on the key) and has been working, now they want quote so got "{k:v, k1:v1, k3:\"v3\"}"

Comment: Like I said, that is not JSON, and it shouldn't be called that way. Any online JSON validator will tell you it is not valid.